# `-%>` tag does not seem to work by default

Tags: ruby, erb

I have an erb script:

```
<% foo="second" %>
first <%= foo %> third
```

When I run this with the `erb` command, it puts a leading blank line in the output:

```
% erb junk

first second third
```

But when I change the closing `%>` to `-%>` in the first line, the script fails unless I use `erb -T -`:

```
~$ erb junk1
/usr/share/ruby/erb.rb:850:in `eval': junk1:1: syntax error, unexpected ';' (SyntaxError)
_erbout = '';  foo="second" -; _erbout.concat "\n"
                              ^
        from /usr/share/ruby/erb.rb:850:in `result'
        from /usr/share/ruby/erb.rb:832:in `run'
        from /bin/erb:133:in `run'
        from /bin/erb:154:in `<main>'
$ erb -T - junk1
first second third
```

I thought `-%>` was supposed to be always recognized as a tag to skip the trailing newline. I am testing these templates to use with Puppet, so I assume Puppet will recognize the `-%>` tag, and this funkiness is just part of the erb command.

Comment: [`ERB#initialize`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new) would suggest otherwise, check the documentation for the `trim_mode` option.

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable a `trim_mode` (`-%>`), you have to instantiate the `ERB` object with trim mode parameter, such as:

```
e = ERB.new(str, nil, '-')
```

Note that `Rails` does not use the stdlib's `ERB` by default - instead, it uses [`erubis`](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/). Documentation on this can feature can be found in [Section 6.3 here](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.06.html):

> Since 2.6.0, '<%= -%>' remove tail spaces and newline. This is for compatibiliy with ERB when trim mode is '-'. '<%= =%>' also removes tail spaces and newlines, and this is Erubis-original enhancement (cooler than '<%= -%>', isn't it?).

See the [`ERB` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new) for more information. Note also that if you have any training spaces after the `-%>`, then this can cause the newline to *not* be trimmed.